# Proof/Disproof of property of perpendicular lines in the Fibonacci grid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, fibonacci-numbers

In my struggle to try to make progress on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583618/rectangle-with-coordinates-of-all-vertices-fibonacci-numbers), I am trying to find a proof or counterexample of the following, stronger, statement:

Denote by $K$ the subset of the Gaussian integers such that the real and imaginary parts are Fibonacci numbers, i.e. $K = \{ x+iy\; |\; x,y \in \Bbb{F} \}$, where $\Bbb{F}$ is the set of (positive) Fibonacci numbers.

Now, $f_1, f_2 \in K$ are such that $\mathrm{Re}\;f_1 > \mathrm{Re}\;f_2$ and $\mathrm{Im}\;f_2 > \mathrm{Im}\;f_1$. This ensures that the line $L_1$ from $f_1$ to $f_2$ has a negative slope in the complex plane.

What I want to prove/disprove is this:

> Draw a line, denoted $L_2$, perpendicular to $L_1$ starting from $f_1$. Then, no matter how long $L_2$ is, it will never contain any point in the set $K$.

The figure shows an example where $f_1 = 2+i$ and $f_2 = 1+5i$. Will the line $L_2$ ever hit another red dot no matter how long you go (to the right)?

[image]

There is one obvious counterexample: If $f_1 = 2+i$ and $f_2 = 1+2i$, $L_2$ will go through the point $3+2i$. This corresponds to the 45-degree case in the question I linked to above, which is a tilted square with the coordinates $2+i, 1+2i, 2+3i, 3+2i$. Another counterexample is the square $(3+i,1+3i,5+3i,3+5i)$

Are there any others? If there aren't, I think the linked question is resolved.

---

Here is what I have done so far:

The line $L_1$ has the same slope as the vector $f_2 - f_1$. Rotating this vector 90 degrees clockwise corresponds to a multiplication by $-i$. This will give the following expression for $L_2$ (parametrized by $k$):

$$L_2 = f_1 + k(-i)(f_2 - f_1) = f_1(1+ki)-kf_2i$$

Using $f_1 = x_1 + iy_1$ and $f_2 = x_2 + iy_2$ we get

$$L_2 = (x_1 + iy_1)(1+ki) - k(x_2 + iy_2) = \underbrace{x_1+k(y_2-y_1)}_{= x_k} + i\underbrace{\left(y_1+k(x_1-x_2)\right)}_{=y_k}$$

Denote the real and imaginary parts of $L_2$ by $x_k$ and $y_k$ respectively.

Now, the hypothesis is that there are no $k$ such that $x_k$ and $y_k$ are simultaneously Fibonacci numbers.

I don't know if it's useful, but identifying the real and imaginary parts gives

$$y_k(y_2-y_1)+x_k(x_2-x_1) = y_1(y_2-y_1)+x_1(x_2-x_1)$$

This is about as far as I have got. There are certain properties of the Fibonacci sequence that may be useful, such as the fact that every $k^{\text{th}}$ number of the sequence is a multiple of $F_k$, but I haven't been able to make use of it.

Comment: I posted a solution to the original question, it is a quite simple inequality: the main idea is that, since the Fibonacci numbers grow quite fast, a line with slope $m\in(0,1)$ through the left-most vertex cannot meet the line with slope $-1/m$ through the right-most vertex in a point having a Fibonacci number as abscissa.